# How to make aws Lambda function run off of new file in s3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that puts files into an S3 bucket. The function organizes the bucket into the format Date/name/files. I want to make a new Lambda function that manipulates the files and adds them into the bucket under the same date. How do I get the second lambda function to recognize the date that the first function used and find the appropriate location to manipulate the files? Currently I'm using

`List<S3ObjectSummary> s3Objects = s3Client.listObjects("TestDate").getObjectSummaries();`

to find the files to manipulate, but that only works if we create a new bucket each time the functions run, which means we can't run both of the functions automatically. Ideally, we would instead use

```
List<S3ObjectSummary> s3Objects = s3Client.listObjects("bucketName", "date/").getObjectSummaries();
```

but I don't know how to get the date. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The question is confusing. What is the order that the two functions run in? Do you want the first function to upload files to the bucket, and then the second function read them from the bucket, modify them, and put the modified version back in the bucket?

Comment: The first function stores the files (JSON files) in the bucket. That part works fine. The second function should kick off at the end of the first, and go through each file, read its contents, and add it to it's own, new, csv file, without disturbing the old ones. The functions both work independent of each other, but linking them has proved difficult.

Comment: Either have the first function store a record somewhere, like DynamoDB, that has the date that the second function needs to use, or have it call the second function directly, passing it the date as a parameter.

Comment: Right, so we tried that, but both of the "input" and "context" parameter don't show us the date in the json that we are passing to it. Here is our current code:

`AWSLambdaClient lambdaClient = new AWSLambdaClient(awsCreds);
InvokeRequest invoke = new InvokeRequest();
invoke.setFunctionName("JsonToCSV");
String payload = "{\"date\":" + "\"" + dateTime + "\"}";
lambdaClient.invoke(invoke.withPayload(payload));`